# I would like some guidance about organizing my effort to start contributing answers

Tags: support

I've benefited for some time now with help from this community.  While I don't consider myself a particular genius, I also know that "anyone can help anyone", so I'd like to start at least trying to give back.  But, just like everyone else I'm sure, I need to be efficient in my efforts (which is why I come to SO!).  And for the record, it's not about the reputation with me, it's about helping others as I have been helped.  Also, it seems like sometimes it's not the content of the question that's the issue, but rather the perspective of the person asking, so sometimes even someone like myself can help because I may have had the same perspective and see the path to the solution where others may not.

I did spend some time looking at a variety of posts here on Meta on the topic of answering but I didn't really have any 'epiphanies'.  Of course I might have missed the best post of all because I don't know the right way to search for the answer I'm seeking.  I am hoping I could either be **(1)** pointed to existing posts I didn't find regarding how to be organized in looking for questions to answer, or maybe also to **(2)** get a range of ideas from those of you who have a little more experience at doing this.  I believe we learn best by listening to those who are already experts.

So, how do most people who answer questions find the questions they're going to answer?  I've always been amazed at how quickly people come to my aid.  How do they do that?  Obviously they have some system by which they make sure the questions they are likely to be able to answer show up in front of their eyes.  It's not intuitively obvious to me the best way to make that happen.

I'm really hoping this is an 'OK' question to be asking here, but I believe it is a legitimate 'support' issue.

Comment: pick a tag you know something about, search for questions on that tag and answer them.

Comment: Pick a tag or set of tags and just watch the questions stream in, when sorting by newest.

Comment: Please do take a look at [answer] so that you're aware of what makes a good answer, Take a look at [ask] so that you're not answering questions which may be closed anyway.

Comment: Yeah, @mike is right. Don't get tempted by low-hanging rotten fruit. They're usually simple to answer (any moron could answer "What library supports XYZ" by searching), but answering this and other off-topic questions can get your answer downvoted and deleted, possibly resulting in an answer ban.

Comment: I had seen the post marked as a previous answer & upon more careful reading did find in the 1st answer some help to get organized, so thanks for making me look again.  I hadn't picked up on that guidance because that post seemed more motivated by how to gain reputation, which is not really my thing; I just want to help, but I need to go about doing it efficiently, that's all.  So I added a few tags and tried to see how the filtering works.  We'll see.  I may still not be in a place to contribute too much for the time being.

Comment: I also noticed as I added some tags that it indicated there is no usage guidance, so maybe I can contribute that way.